# Laravel 5.5 echo unable to listen to channel

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I am currently using laravel-echo along with with pusher to set up my channel and broadcast however there seems to be some issues creating the listener onto the channel.

There should be a message on the pusher dashboard indicating that the channel is being listened to when the page is entered but nothing is being displayed

**Initializing Echo Listener**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            try{
                window.Echo.channel('chat-room')
                .listen('scannedQR', (e) => {
                    console.log("event has been triggered");
                    alert('event has been triggered');
                });
                alert('success');
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e);
                alert(e);
            }
}
```

**Bootstrap**

```
 import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
 
 window.Lover = "LOVER!";
 
 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: 'key',
     // cluster: 'mt1',
     cluster:'ap1',
     encrypted: true
 });
```

***Echo Object*** -> `console.log(JSON.safeStringify(window.Echo));`

```
{
  "options": {
    "broadcaster": "pusher",
    "key": key,
    "cluster": cluster,
    "encrypted": true
  },
  "connector": {
    "_defaultOptions": {
      "auth": {
        "headers": {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "oIywz9kkxhVbl109qOqXMy0NVrUCR5AZlYR5apPc"
        }
      },
      "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
      "userAuthentication": {
        "endpoint": "/broadcasting/user-auth",
        "headers": {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "oIywz9kkxhVbl109qOqXMy0NVrUCR5AZlYR5apPc"
        }
      },
      "broadcaster": "pusher",
      "csrfToken": null,
      "host": null,
      "key": key,
      "namespace": "App.Events",
      "cluster": "ap1",
      "encrypted": true
    },
    "pusher": {
      "key": key,
      "config": {
        "activityTimeout": 120000,
        "cluster": "ap1",
        "httpPath": "/pusher",
        "httpPort": 80,
        "httpsPort": 443,
        "pongTimeout": 30000,
        "statsHost": "stats.pusher.com",
        "unavailableTimeout": 10000,
        "wsPath": "",
        "wsPort": 80,
        "wssPort": 443,
        "enableStats": false,
        "httpHost": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com",
        "useTLS": true,
        "wsHost": "ws-ap1.pusher.com"
      },
      "channels": {
        "channels": {}
      },
      "global_emitter": {
        "callbacks": {
          "_callbacks": {}
        },
        "global_callbacks": []
      },
      "sessionID": 299457458,
      "timeline": {
        "key": key,
        "session": 299457458,
        "events": [
          {
            "instances": 1,
            "timestamp": 1660358957487
          },
          {
            "state": "connecting",
            "timestamp": 1660358957538
          },
          {
            "cached": true,
            "transport": "xhr_streaming",
            "latency": 410,
            "timestamp": 1660358957539
          },
          {
            "cid": 1,
            "transport": "xhr_streamings",
            "timestamp": 1660358957539
          },
          {
            "cid": 1,
            "state": "initialized",
            "timestamp": 1660358957539
          },
          {
            "cid": 1,
            "state": "connecting",
            "timestamp": 1660358957541
          },
          {
            "cid": 1,
            "state": "open",
            "timestamp": 1660358957974
          },
          {
            "state": "connected",
            "params": {
              "socket_id": "17356.8786996"
            },
            "timestamp": 1660358957976
          }
        ],
        "options": {
          "cluster": cluster,
          "features": [
            "ws"
          ],
          "params": {},
          "limit": 50,
          "level": 6,
          "version": "7.3.0"
        },
        "sent": 0,
        "uniqueID": 1
      },
      "connection": {
        "callbacks": {
          "_callbacks": {
            "_connected": [
              {},
              {}
            ],
            "_message": [
              {},
              {}
            ],
            "_connecting": [
              {},
              {}
            ],
            "_disconnected": [
              {},
              {}
            ],
            "_error": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        },
        "global_callbacks": [],
        "state": "connected",
        "connection": {
          "callbacks": {
            "_callbacks": {
              "_tls_only": [
                {}
              ],
              "_refused": [
                {}
              ],
              "_backoff": [
                {}
              ],
              "_retry": [
                {}
              ],
              "_message": [
                {}
              ],
              "_ping": [
                {}
              ],
              "_activity": [
                {}
              ],
              "_error": [
                {}
              ],
              "_closed": [
                {}
              ]
            }
          },
          "global_callbacks": [],
          "id": "17356.8786996",
          "transport": {
            "callbacks": {
              "_callbacks": {
                "_error": [
                  {}
                ],
                "_closed": [
                  {},
                  {}
                ],
                "_message": [
                  {}
                ],
                "_activity": [
                  {}
                ]
              }
            },
            "global_callbacks": [],
            "hooks": {
              "urls": {},
              "handlesActivityChecks": false,
              "supportsPing": true
            },
            "name": "xhr_streaming",
            "priority": 1,
            "key": key,
            "options": {
              "key": key,
              "useTLS": true,
              "hostNonTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:80",
              "hostTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:443",
              "httpPath": "/pusher"
            },
            "state": "open",
            "id": 1,
            "socket": {
              "hooks": {},
              "session": "428/90n18c0a",
              "location": {
                "base": base,
                "queryString": "?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.3.0"
              },
              "readyState": 1,
              "stream": {
                "callbacks": {
                  "_callbacks": {
                    "_chunk": [
                      {}
                    ],
                    "_finished": [
                      {}
                    ],
                    "_buffer_too_long": [
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "global_callbacks": [],
                "hooks": {},
                "method": "POST",
                "url": url,
                "position": 2188,
                "xhr": {}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "key": key,
        "options": {
          "activityTimeout": 120000,
          "pongTimeout": 30000,
          "unavailableTimeout": 10000,
          "useTLS": true
        },
        "usingTLS": true,
        "errorCallbacks": {},
        "connectionCallbacks": {},
        "handshakeCallbacks": {},
        "strategy": {
          "strategy": {
            "strategy": {
              "trueBranch": {
                "strategies": [
                  {
                    "strategies": [
                      {
                        "name": "ws",
                        "priority": 3,
                        "transport": {
                          "manager": {
                            "options": {
                              "lives": 2,
                              "minPingDelay": 10000,
                              "maxPingDelay": 120000
                            },
                            "livesLeft": 2
                          },
                          "transport": {
                            "hooks": {
                              "urls": {},
                              "handlesActivityChecks": false,
                              "supportsPing": false
                            }
                          },
                          "minPingDelay": 10000,
                          "maxPingDelay": 120000
                        },
                        "options": {
                          "key": key,
                          "useTLS": true,
                          "hostNonTLS": "ws-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                          "hostTLS": "ws-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                          "httpPath": ""
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "loop": true,
                    "failFast": false,
                    "timeout": 15000,
                    "timeoutLimit": 60000
                  },
                  {
                    "strategy": {
                      "trueBranch": {
                        "strategies": [
                          {
                            "trueBranch": {
                              "strategies": [
                                {
                                  "strategies": [
                                    {
                                      "trueBranch": {
                                        "name": "xhr_streaming",
                                        "priority": 1,
                                        "transport": {
                                          "manager": {
                                            "options": {
                                              "lives": 2,
                                              "minPingDelay": 10000,
                                              "maxPingDelay": 120000
                                            },
                                            "livesLeft": 2
                                          },
                                          "transport": {},
                                          "minPingDelay": 10000,
                                          "maxPingDelay": 120000
                                        },
                                        "options": {
                                          "key": key,
                                          "useTLS": true,
                                          "hostNonTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                                          "hostTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                                          "httpPath": "/pusher"
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "falseBranch": {
                                        "name": "xdr_streaming",
                                        "priority": 1,
                                        "transport": {
                                          "transport": {
                                            "hooks": {
                                              "urls": {},
                                              "handlesActivityChecks": false,
                                              "supportsPing": true
                                            }
                                          },
                                          "minPingDelay": 10000,
                                          "maxPingDelay": 120000
                                        },
                                        "options": {
                                          "key": key,
                                          "useTLS": true,
                                          "hostNonTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                                          "hostTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                                          "httpPath": "/pusher"
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ],
                                  "loop": true,
                                  "failFast": false,
                                  "timeout": 15000,
                                  "timeoutLimit": 60000
                                },
                                {
                                  "strategy": {
                                    "strategies": [
                                      {
                                        "trueBranch": {
                                          "name": "xhr_polling",
                                          "priority": 1,
                                          "transport": {
                                            "hooks": {
                                              "urls": {},
                                              "handlesActivityChecks": false,
                                              "supportsPing": true
                                            }
                                          },
                                          "options": {
                                            "key": key,
                                            "useTLS": true,
                                            "hostNonTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                                            "hostTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                                            "httpPath": "/pusher"
                                          }
                                        },
                                        "falseBranch": {
                                          "name": "xdr_polling",
                                          "priority": 1,
                                          "transport": {
                                            "hooks": {
                                              "urls": {},
                                              "handlesActivityChecks": false,
                                              "supportsPing": true
                                            }
                                          },
                                          "options": {
                                            "key": key,
                                            "useTLS": true,
                                            "hostNonTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                                            "hostTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                                            "httpPath": "/pusher"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ],
                                    "loop": true,
                                    "failFast": false,
                                    "timeout": 15000,
                                    "timeoutLimit": 60000
                                  },
                                  "options": {
                                    "delay": 4000
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "loop": true,
                        "failFast": false,
                        "timeout": 15000,
                        "timeoutLimit": 60000
                      },
                      "falseBranch": {
                        "strategies": [
                          {
                            "name": "sockjs",
                            "priority": 1,
                            "transport": {
                              "hooks": {
                                "file": "sockjs",
                                "urls": {},
                                "handlesActivityChecks": true,
                                "supportsPing": false
                              }
                            },
                            "options": {
                              "key": key,
                              "useTLS": true,
                              "hostNonTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                              "hostTLS": "sockjs-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                              "httpPath": "/pusher"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "loop": true,
                        "failFast": false,
                        "timeout": 15000,
                        "timeoutLimit": 60000
                      }
                    },
                    "options": {
                      "delay": 2000
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "transports": {
            "wss": {
              "name": "wss",
              "priority": 3,
              "transport": {
                "minPingDelay": 10000,
                "maxPingDelay": 120000
              },
              "options": {
                "key": key,
                "useTLS": true,
                "hostNonTLS": "ws-ap1.pusher.com:80",
                "hostTLS": "ws-ap1.pusher.com:443",
                "httpPath": ""
              }
            }
          },
          "ttl": 1800000,
          "usingTLS": true
        },
        "runner": null,
        "unavailableTimer": {
          "timer": null
        },
        "activityTimeout": 120000,
        "activityTimer": {
          "timer": 5
        },
        "socket_id": "17356.8786996"
      },
      "user": {
        "callbacks": {
          "_callbacks": {}
        },
        "global_callbacks": [],
        "signin_requested": false,
        "user_data": null,
        "serverToUserChannel": null
      }
    },
    "channels": {}
  }
}
```

*Pusher Dashboard doesn't show that channel is being listened to*

***EDIT***
It currently shows on the pusher dashboard that the channel is being listened to but laravel-echo doesn't catch the event on the front end

Comment: try this command php artisan queue:work

Comment: The event class extends from ShouldBroadcastNow which means I shouldn't need the queue right? @UmerFayyaz

Comment: i think php artisan queue:work need. in this link they also specify https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#queue-configuration

Comment: you should have jobs table in database and .env queue_connection = database

Comment: @UmerFayyaz But i actually have no issues broadcasting the event, I can see the event being created on pusher debugger site. Laravel-echo just isn't capturing the event